# CSS, how to put a div inside a div that is responsive?

Tags: css, html

I am trying to create a box with 2 contents side by side that is responsive. I want the divs to have separate classes so when I add the javascript, each content will be unique from the other. Can somebody help me out?

html:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

    <style type="text/css">
        .outer {
            border: 1px solid black;
            }
        .inner-top {
            float:center;
            text-align: center;
            }
        .inner-left {
            border: 1px solid black;
            text-align: center;
            }
        .inner-right {
            border:1px solid black;
            text-align: center;
            }
    </style>

    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner-top">
            <div class="inner-left">
                <p>
                inner left
                </p>        
            </div>
            <div class="inner-right">
                <p>
                inner right
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: I should explain myself a bit more in detail, I want to keep the outer class as a container, use the inner-top class as the inner container for the inner-left and inner-right classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the effect that you're going for?

http://jsfiddle.net/psLu7/

[image]

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.outer {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.inner-top {
  /* float:center; */
  text-align: center;
  overflow: auto;
 }

 .inner-left {
   border: 1px solid black;
   text-align: center;
   float: left;
   width: 50%;
 }

 .inner-right {
   border:1px solid black;
   text-align: center;
   float: left;
   width: 50%;
 }
```

Comment: If you were a prophet, I would follow you to the depths of mordor! amazing, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<style type="text/css">
    .outer {
        border: 1px solid black;
        }
    .inner-top {
        float:center;
        text-align: center;
        width:100%;
        position:relative;
        }
    .inner-left {
        border: 1px solid black;
        text-align: center;
        float:left;
        width:49%;
        position:relative;
        }
    .inner-right {
        border:1px solid black;
        text-align: center;
        float:left;
        width:49%;
        position:relative;
        }
</style>
```

Here is the jsfiddle I created - http://jsfiddle.net/PYAgx/

Comment: Thanks for the response! however, I should expalin myself a bit more in detail, I want to keep the outer class as a container, use the inner-top class as the inner container for the inner-left and inner-right classes.

Comment: I did not change your html. The `outer` class is the container for `inner-top` which is the container for both `inner-left` and `inner-right` I don't understand what you are asking for then.